# How to Display an Output and End the Program at the Same Time if the User Enters 0 or Less

Tags: c++

Hi so I want to end my program if t1, t2 or t3 <= 0. But I want to display this error message before it ends :

cout << "Error!\n\n" << "Runner's time must be greater than 0.\n" << "Rerun the program and try again.\n";

I have tried doing it with while but it just makes my program output window go on forever if 0 isn't entered. Can someone please help?

```
//This program shows the rankings of three runners in a race
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string runner1, runner2, runner3;
    double t1, t2, t3;
    
    cout << "Enter the name of the first runner : ";
    cin >> runner1;
    cout << "Enter the time taken for the first runner to finish the race in seconds : ";
    cin >> t1;
    cout << "\n";
    
    cout << "Enter the name of the second runner : ";
    cin >> runner2;
    cout << "Enter the time taken for the second runner to finish the race in seconds : ";
    cin >> t2;
    cout << "\n";
    
    cout << "Enter the name of the third runner : ";
    cin >> runner3;
    cout << "Enter the time taken for the third runner to finish the race in seconds : ";
    cin >> t3;
    cout << "\n";
    
    cout <<"--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"<< "\n" ;
    
    if (t1 < t2 && t2 < t3)
    {
        cout << "Running Race Rankings\n\n";
        cout << "1st place : " << runner1 << "\n" << "2nd place : " << runner2 << "\n" << "3rd place : " << runner3 << "\n";
    }
    
    else if (t1 < t3 && t3 < t2)
    {
        cout << "Running Race Rankings\n\n";
        cout << "1st place : " << runner1 << "\n" << "2nd place : " << runner3 << "\n" << "3rd place : " << runner2 << "\n";
    }
    
    else if (t2 < t1 && t1 < t3)
    {
        cout << "Running Race Rankings\n\n";
        cout << "1st place : " << runner2 << "\n" << "2nd place : " << runner1 << "\n" << "3rd place : " << runner3 << "\n";
    }
    
    else if (t2 < t3 && t3 < t1)
    {
        cout << "Running Race Rankings\n\n";
        cout << "1st place : " << runner2 << "\n" << "2nd place : " << runner3 << "\n" << "3rd place : " << runner1 << "\n";
    }
    
    else if (t3 < t1 && t1 < t2)
    {
        cout << "Running Race Rankings\n\n";
        cout << "1st place : " << runner3 << "\n" << "2nd place : " << runner1 << "\n" << "3rd place : " << runner2 << "\n";
    }
    
    else if (t3 < t2 && t2 < t1)
    {
        cout << "Running Race Rankings\n\n";
        cout << "1st place : " << runner3 << "\n" << "2nd place : " << runner2 << "\n" << "3rd place : " << runner1 << "\n";
    }
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cout << "Enter the name of the first runner : ";
cin >> runner1
cout << "Enter the time taken for the first runner to finish the race in seconds : ";
cin >> t1;
if(t1 <= 0){ 
cout << "Error!\n\n" << "Runner's time must be greater than 0.\n" << "Rerun the program and try again.\n";
exit(1);
}
cout << "\n";
```

You've said t1,t2 and t3 shouldn't be equal to 0. I customized the code by looking the error phrase. If you want to use this code as you said above your question, you can remove the `=` sign from `t1 <= 0`

`exit(1)` is a function to terminate the program. You can use this function whenever you want to end your program.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked!!

And yes it's supposed to be t1, t2, t3 is not less than or equal to 0